# How to handle deleting parent foreign key object?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say my database is for ecommerce store. Database holds records of users and orders. I have 2 tables 'users' and 'orders'.
'orders' table have userId column(foreign key) that reference to 'users' table id column.
When I want to delete a user- it throws an error because the 'orders' table have a record referencing this user's id. So how should I handle this?

I found 3 ways to overcome this.

1. not use foreign keys
2. use 'ON DELETE CASCADE' so when i delete user from 'users' table it will delete related order records of that user automaticaly.(is it a good idea?)
3. delete all child records and then delete parent record.

What is the best way?

Comment: I never like using CASCADE as it can be dangerous. You can just put a flag on deleted rows saying they're 'deleted'.

Comment: Not deleting user records - which sounds like a very bad idea. Just flag them as inactive if necessary

Comment: You need the order records, even if the user is deleted, if you want your e-commerce sales to sum up correctly.

Comment: If you want to delete the associated records, use `on delete cascade`; I don't think there's much argument there. If you want to do something fancier, like archive the orders and user, you'll have to say more about your circumstances. The wisdom of deleting order records is another question

Comment: @BillKarwin is absolutely right, you must not delete past orders data, even if the user is deleted! What will happen to your various tax declarations, year-end financial statements, if you deleted sales? I think your tax authority will consider this as tax fraud and would likely to issue a fine or even prosecute you! General practice is that you need to remove any personally identifiable data from the user table, but not from the orders table and mark the user record as deleted.

Comment: Never, ever, delete a row in a commerce application. I repeat, never delete it. Just soft-delete them with a status column. There are a myriad of reasons to keep the data, specially related to finances, accounting, auditing, taxes, legal, liabilities, reporting, business intelligence, marketing campaigns, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple question of how do you delete a record and it's references...

Foreign keys are critical for the integrity of your database. Without foreign keys you easily wind up with records that refer to objects which no longer exists. Don't remove them.

Manually deleting the referencing rows is error prone and will break when you change the schema.

`on delete cascade` allows you to have referential integrity, and also be able to delete records.

---

The comments got into the larger question of whether deleting user and order records are a good idea. There is not enough information in your question to know what is best. That would be another question.

However, even if you decide to use a status field to set users and orders as inactive (a timestamp, not a flag, because you'll want to know when the user was deactivated), you *still* want to set up the tables with `on delete cascade` so when you eventually do delete inactive records (for example, perhaps an annual cleanup, or for testing, or due to a mistake) the delete will work.

Comment: Technically correct, but I would not recommend to do this. It's much safer to soft-delete rows.